# Problem importing Drupal to a CentOS 6.2 Server: The smtp authentication module does not work

Tags: users

I have a problem with a Drupal site running on Centos 6.2 server, Apache 2.21.15, and using PHP 5.3. The Drupal installation was made in a Windows XP computer using Wamp, it makes use of email for notifications when a new content is created, etc. In this computer (XP), it works like a charm, sending emails and doing everything right. Now that I migrated the site, copying the appropriate files from Drupal, importing the database, using phpMyAdmin, everything seems to be working right but the smtp authentication module doesn't work; there is no error, but I don't receive the test email inside this modules. Other thing funny, I've installed Drupal 7 in the server, and the smtp authentication module, and it works just fine. I guess that could be a permission problem but I can't find how to fix it.

Comment: I'm glad you got this working :) I'm commenting now afterwards just to point out that breaking the text up in smaller chunks, and removing some details that are not relevant, will likely give you a higher question vote in the future. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem was caused from the fact I used the development snapshot instead of the stable release. Once I installed the stable release, all worked perfectly.